# Why doesn't combobox update edited item model?

Tags: vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

Combobox is defined this way:

```js
<template>
   <v-combobox
   clearable
   v-model="values"
   :items="items"
   item-text="name"
   ></v-combobox>
</template>

<script>
data () {
    return {
        items: [
            {"id": 2, "name": "tree"},
            {"id": 4, "name": "grass"},
            {"id": 5, "name": "freeze"},
            {"id": 9, "name": "moss"}
        ],
        values: ''
    },
    watch: {
        values () {
            console.log(this.values) // Output: {__ob__: Observer}: e.g. id: 2, name: tree
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Combobox items are editable: I can select one of them (then the Observer is logged in the console), and edit it, but then nothing happens in the console.

How to update the model with edited entries?

EDIT: just discovered that the model gets updated when leaving the combobox field (onBlur). How to change this behavior to e.g. onKeyDown?

EDIT2: another discovery: when clicking outside the combobox, `values` get reset (undefined). So, only onChange event can be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve it, however I consider it rather as a non elegant workaround.

To make things clear: I needed both `id` and `name` to be passed to the `combobox`. The `id` is read-only, while `name` entry has to be editable. `id` gets passed to the `values` model thanks to `item-value="id"` added to the `combobox` definition (it's already commented in discussion below *Germano Buss Niehues*' answer). `name` was only updated by the model when item was selected, but not after it was edited. And the edited value of `name` is the thing I needed.

Eventually, I added the plain HTML `id` field to the `combobox`:

```html
<template>
   <v-combobox
     clearable
     id="words_names"
     v-model="values"
     :items="items"
     item-text="name"
   ></v-combobox>
</template>
```

and read the final value with:

`document.getElementById("words_names").value`

As I said, not very elegant but does its job...

Answer (score 0):

the attribute `item-value` is missing, you can do something like this:

```
 items: [
            {"id": 2, "name": "tree", "value" : 1},
            {"id": 4, "name": "grass", "value" : 2},
            {"id": 5, "name": "freeze", "value" : 3},
            {"id": 9, "name": "moss", "value" : 4}
        ],
```

and in your tag

```
  <v-combobox
   clearable
   v-model="values"
   :items="items"
   item-text="name"
   item-value = "value"
   @change = "values()"
   ></v-combobox>
```

Comment: I added `item-value="id"` but it didn't change the model update issue... Still, the model gets updated on leaving the combobox field, not on changing its values.

Comment: edited the answer, added @change to the tag, try again

Comment: What does this `values()` entry refer to? Is it a reference to model `values`? Unfortunately, I got an error: `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _vm.values is not a function"`.